# Remove space after backslashes in listings

Tags: listings

I'm trying to write some code inside a listing, however, every backslash adds a space to the right of it and I'm trying to keep it as it is. How could I possibly remove them?

```
\begin{lstlisting}[showstringspaces=false]
1   package org.jmlspecs.samples.jmlrefman
2
3   public abstract class IntHeap{
4
5   //@ public model non_null int[] elements;
6
7   /*@ public normal_behaviour
8     @    requires elements.length >= 1;
9     @    assignable \nothing
10    @    ensures \result 
11    @    == (\max int j;
12    @            0 <= j && j < elements.length;
13    @            elements[j]);
14    @*/
15   public abstract /*@ pure @*/ int largest();
16
17   //@ ensures \result == elements.length;
18   public abstract /*@ pure @*/ int size();
19   };
\end{lstlisting}
```

For example, line 9 shows as

`9     @    assignable \ nothing`

instead of

`9     @    assignable \nothing`

EDIT:
Was told to add a minimal working example so here is one:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}


\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}

\maketitle

\section{example}

\begin{lstlisting}
1 public class BubbleSort {    
2   /*@
3     @ requires arr != null; 
4     @ ensures \forall int k; 0 <= k && k < arr.length -1;
5     @           arr[k] > arr[k+1];
6     @*/
7  public static void sort(int [] arr) {        
8    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
9      for (int j = arr.length-1; j > i; j--) {
10       if (arr[j-1] < arr[j]) {
11          int tmp = arr[j];
12        arr[j] = arr[j-1];
13      arr[j-1] = tmp;
14           }
15       }
16     }
17   }
18 }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I complete your example in an `article` document loading only the package `listings`, the output is as expected, without the space. Can you update your example to a compilable document that reproduces the error?

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: Added a compilable document now, sorry!

Comment: your new example only has one `\ ` in `\forall` and it [renders with no space as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yAUD.png)

Comment: In my case, it does and not only that but it also adds spaces between the letters of forall.
[example](https://imgur.com/a/hvJeqbD)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SX! What you see are not real spaces in your code, but this is the result of the `listings` package placing all characters in columns that are 0.6em wide each. This is actually a feature of this package.

You may want to consult the [manual for the `listings` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) and try these different options (together or individually):

- set the option `basewidth` to something less than 0.6em,
- set the option `columns` to `flexible` or `fullflexible`,
- set the option `basicstyle` to `{\ttfamily}` to use a monospaced font family.

By the way, the `listings` package can add line numbers automatically. Just add the option `numbers=left`, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fixed, basewidth=0.5em, basicstyle={\ttfamily}]  % set options here
1 public class BubbleSort {    
2   /*@
3     @ requires arr != null; 
4     @ ensures \forall int k; 0 <= k && k < arr.length -1;
5     @           arr[k] > arr[k+1];
6     @*/
7  public static void sort(int [] arr) {        
8    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
9      for (int j = arr.length-1; j > i; j--) {
10       if (arr[j-1] < arr[j]) {
11          int tmp = arr[j];
12        arr[j] = arr[j-1];
13      arr[j-1] = tmp;
14           }
15       }
16     }
17   }
18 }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]